# Bottlepy serve static file with dynamic root

Tags: python, routes, bottle

Serve static file in bottlepy is as simple as this:

```
@route('statics/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='assets')
```

Thus the static file served should be in `assets` directory.

So, this one: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/statics/jquery.js` will refer to `assets/jquery.js`

So far, I don't find any problem.
But let's say, I want to make a framework with application folder contains some models, views and controllers. 
The directory structure is like this:

```
|---applications
|   |--- assets
|---start.py
|---core
    |--- __init__.py
```

In `core/__init__.py` I put a function to run bottle and route assets directory

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file

@route('assets/<filepath:path>')
def _serve_assets(path):
    # I want the root to be dynamic, because It is not always be applications
    return static_file(path, root=os.path.join('applications', 'assets'))

def framework_start(application_path = 'applications', **kwargs):
    # A lot of logic
    run(**kwargs)
```

And on `start.py` i do this:

```
from core import framework_start
framework_start(application_path = 'applications')
```

So far the static files served as expected. But I want it to still works even after I change the code in start.py into this:

```
framework_start(application_path = 'app')
```

and the directory structure into this

```
|---apps
|   |--- assets
|---start.py
|---core
    |--- __init__.py
```

So, how to do that? How to make a static routing with dynamic root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return static_file(filename, root=filefolder)
```

The first argument is the name only, and the second is the folder that contains it.

You know where the [docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html#static-files) are...

From your comments I think I got it.

If you want the template to have the path, you need to send it to bottle by something like `<input type="hidden" name="arch"...` and recieve it with `request.GET.get('arch', '')` and use it with `root=...`.

Comment: Hi, I absolutely know where the docs are. Thanks for point it again.
My question is HOW TO MAKE THE SECOND ARGUMENT DYNAMIC? As for templates, we have TEMPLATE_PATH that can be set dynamically (changed or runtime). I want to do that for static_file

Comment: The idea is to use a var instead of a constant value for root. I use something like `static_file(filename, root='./{}'.format(arch[-1]))`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really clear with this. But is it means that I should use this in my html: <script type="text/javascript" src="app/my_static.js"></script> ?